# SQL Server differential backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-backups

I took a full backup from `(x)` server and restored it to `(y)` server and after that, started taking differential backups from `(x)` server and restored them on a daily basis to `(y)` server.

If I take another full backup from `(x)` server, should I restore it to `(y)` server? Or, can I continue restoring the differential backup only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A differential backup contains changed data pages since the last full backup. As such, if you take another full backup, you'll also need to restore that to your other server.

Note: if you were instead using *log* backups, you could continue to restore them regardless of whether you'd taken another full or differential backup.

Comment: thanks for your reply. if i have a differential backup before a while from the full backup every day. is this will be fine. to be more clear the scenario will be as below:-   1- take a full backup from the DB and restore it to another server    2- create job to take a differential backup on daily basis and after that take a full backup "the full backup is needed for another purposes "   3- restore that differential backup to the another server. So i think in this case i'll not lose any changes on the database since the differential taken before a while from full backup on daily is this right?